# Change font-face generated by webpack 5

Tags: webpack, webpack-5

I'm using webpack 5, and trying to make it work with webfonts.

The output directory is like this:

```
wwwroot
  bin
    mybundle.css
    mybundle.js
  fonts
    roboto.woff
    roboto.woff2
```

The output:

```js
output: {
  path: path.join(__dirname, './wwwroot/'),
  publicPath: '',                           // prevents "Error: Automatic publicPath is not supported"
  // ...
},
```

The resolver:

```js
{
  test: /\.woff2?$/i,
  type: 'asset/resource',
  generator: { filename: 'bin/[base]' },
}
```

Everything seems to work, except the generated font-face is wrong:

```css
@font-face {
  font-family: "Roboto";
  font-style: normal;
  font-display: swap;
  font-weight: 400;
  src: url(fonts/roboto.woff2) format("woff2");    /* !!! PROBLEM !!! */
}
```

It generates `url(fonts/roboto.woff2)` instead of `url(/wwwroot/fonts/roboto.woff2)`. So the css won't find the webfonts.

How do I prepend a `/wwwroot/`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution:

```js
output: {
  publicPath: '/wwwroot/',
  // ...
},
```